# Is it a good idea to spread argparse args across multiple files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a tool that has a bunch of subfunction files that usually have distinct arguments. The subfunctions are extensions or alternate implementations of the processes that happen when the program runs.

I'm thinking of putting the core arguments in my main.py folder and allowing the subfunction files to call for their own arguments.

I'm thinking something like this 
**main.py:**

```
import config

parser.add_argument('run_name') 
parser.add_argument('-modules', nargs='*')
parser.add_argument('-v') 
... 

config.parser = parser
from submodules import * 

args = config.parser.parse_args()
def main():
    ...
```

**drink_beer.py:**

```
import config
config.parser.add_argument('-beer_folderpath') 
config.parser.add_argument('-bac_max') 

def sub_main(args):
    ...
```

**To Run the program:** 
I'd specify The core arguments then the arguments of any subfunction files.

```
python main.py driving_sim_december -v -modules drink_beer -beer_folderpath /home/canman -bac_max .35
```

Is this a good Idea? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you add example on how you would do this? E.g. would you run `main.py` and then pass arguments for each different module? Or run `main.py drink_beer` and then the special arguments? Or would you run `drink_beer.py` and then just the special arguments?

Comment: Usually I'd have all the arguments defined at the top level (i.e. in `main.py`) and then have the *implementation* of those behaviors in their own modules.  If you have so many arguments that even defining them in a single place is unwieldy, I might suggest that they shouldn't be command line args and should instead be some kind of config file (e.g. nested JSON data).

Comment: @MegaIng I made the edit. I was thinking the first option.

Comment: @DNS_Jeezus The better way is by using `click` https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/.